# Let $P_X$ and $P_Y$ are the projection matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations, projection-matrices

Let $P_X$ and $P_Y$ are the projection matrices into $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$, respectively.Show that $P_XP_Y = 0$ iff $C(X)\perp C(Y)$. Here $C(X),C(Y)$ mean the column spaces of the matrices $X,Y$ respectively.
I don't know how to approach this. Please help!

Comment: $P_XP_Y$ is the projection onto $Y$, followed by the projection onto $X$. If this is zero, then that means the only element in $C(X)\cap C(Y)$ is the zero vector. This is perhaps not a full proof, but the general idea.

Comment: How do you define "projection matrix"?